# Variable in JavaScript callback functions always gets last value in loop?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm trying to do the following:

I have a set of images and select (dropdown) HTML elements, 30 of each one. I'm trying to use AddEventListener on a loop from 1 to 30 so that when I change the value of the select, the image src is updated (and the image changes).

The AddEventListener function is this one:

```
function AddEventListener(element, eventType, handler, capture)
{
    if (element.addEventListener)
        element.addEventListener(eventType, handler, capture);
    else if (element.attachEvent)
        element.attachEvent("on" + eventType, handler);
}
```

I tried this and it worked:

```
var urlfolderanimalimages = "http://localhost/animalimages/";
var testselect = "sel15";
var testimg = "i15";

AddEventListener(document.getElementById(testselect), "change", function(e) {
    document.getElementById(testimg).src = urlfolderanimalimages + document.getElementById(testselect).value;
    document.getElementById(testimg).style.display = 'inline';

    if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
    else e.returnResult = false;
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
    else e.cancelBubble = true;
}, false);
```

But then I tried to call it in a loop and it doesn't work. The event is added, but when I change any select, it will update the last one (the image with id i30).

```
var urlfolderanimalimages = "http://localhost/animalimages/";

for (k=1;k<=30;k++) {
    var idselect = "sel" + k;
    var idimage = "i" + k;

    AddEventListener(document.getElementById(idselect), "change", function(e) {
        document.getElementById(idimage).src = urlfolderanimalimages + document.getElementById(idselect).value;
        document.getElementById(idimage).style.display = 'inline';

        if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
        else e.returnResult = false;
        if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
        else e.cancelBubble = true;
    }, false);

}
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm new to JavaScript (and programming in general), so sorry for the vomit-inducing code :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you are 'closing' over the *same variable*.

**var does not declare a variable**<sup>1</sup>. It simply annotates a 'stop look-up' for an identifier within a given execution context.

Please see [Javascript Closures "FAQ Notes"](http://jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/closures.html) for all the nice details. The sections on 'execution context' and 'scope chain' are most interesting.

The common idiom is perform a double-binding to create a new execution context.

E.g.

```
var k
for (k = 1; k < 10; k++) {
  setTimeout((function (_k) {
    return function () {
      alert(_k)
    }
  })(k), k * 100)
}
```

---

As of JavaScript 5th Edition there is [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (it can also be implemented in 3rd edition such as [bind from prototype.js](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/function/bind)), which can be used as such:

```
var k
for (k = 1; k < 10; k++) {
  setTimeout((function () {
     alert(this)
  }).bind(k), k * 100)
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> This construct *is* referred to as a Variable Declaration in the ECMAScript specification. However, this statements, as misleading as it may be viewed, is stressed to bring home a point: also see "variable hoisting".

Comment: Thank you very much, pst. Honestly I'm really new to this so I didn't quite grasp it last night (although it was really late and I was really tired, so that might have contributed to it :p). I'll give it another read today and see if I can make it work. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

I also found this solution at http://meshfields.de/event-listeners-for-loop/:

```
var myArr = [0,1,2,3]; 

for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i+=1) { 

(function (i) { 

    document.getElementById('myDOMelement' myArr[i]).onclick = function () { 

        if (window.console.firebug !== undefined) { 
            console.log('myDOMelement' myArr[i]); 
        } 
        else { 
                alert('myDOMelement' myArr[i]); 
        } 
        }; 
    }) (i); 
}
```