# undefined variable when loop variable passed to callback function

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Variable in JavaScript callback functions always gets last value in loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520587/variable-in-javascript-callback-functions-always-gets-last-value-in-loop)

I  am not able to pass the value of k to the callback function of fadeOut function.
my loop is as given below.

```
 for(var k=0;k<image1.length;k++)
 {

    $(img[k]).fadeOut(200,function(k) {
        alert(k);
        $(this).attr('src', image2[k]);
        $(this).fadeIn(200);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jQuery `fadeOut` function takes a callback function with no arguments. From the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/), "The callback is not sent any arguments". If you want to capture the value of `k`, do something like the following:

```
for(var k=0;k<image1.length;k++) {
    (function(k) {
        $(img[k]).fadeOut(200,function() {
            alert(k);
            $(this).attr('src', image2[k]);
            $(this).fadeIn(200);
        });
    })(k);
}
```

Comment: 10x for the help works perfect..

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to do something like this to give the callback access to your variable:

```
for (var k = 0; k < image1.length; k++) {
    (function(k) {
        $(img[k]).fadeOut(200, function() {
            alert(k);
            this.src = image2[k];
            $(this).fadeIn(200);
        });
    })(k);
}
```

Comment: 10x @Blender..this too works.