# javascript - how to call closure in loop

Tags: javascript, loops, closures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing functions to setTimeout in a loop: always the last value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425062/passing-functions-to-settimeout-in-a-loop-always-the-last-value)

I know I need to use closure to deal with problem, but I'm not sure how; 
I have function, where I get data from server:

```
function loadGraph(chartDataStreams) { //length of chartDataStreams is two

  initCharts(); //init charts area
  for (c in chartDataStreams) {
    var chartData = [];
    alert(c); // says : 0, then 1
    getDataFromServer(chartDataStreams[c].x, chartDataStreams[c].y,function (data) {
       for (d in data.datapoints) {
         var item = { date: new Date(data.datapoints[d].at), value:data.datapoints[d].value };
         chartData.push(item);
        }
      alert(c); // says: 1 then 1
      updateGraphData(chartData); 

    });
  }
}
```

in this function I need to call updateGraphData, which updates graph data provider with chartData. Problem is that in chartData I don't have just the actual data but also the data from previous loop cycle. I think this the right place to use closures, but I'm not sure how.. Do you have any ideas?

//edit: I put the declaration of chartData by mistake outside the getDataFromServer function, but I've got still one problem: check the edited code. From the second alert I want to say 0 and 1, not just 1,1

Comment: Is there a reason your declaring `chartData` twice?  Also, can you describe what is not working, or what are the actual results vs expected results?

Comment: and better to see `updateGraphData` implementation too. and try to empty charData before loop just write chartData = []; inside anonymous function and delete second declaration

Comment: also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520587/variable-in-javascript-callback-functions-always-gets-last-value-in-loop and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example?rq=1

Comment: gosh, I was idiot :-D I copy pasted my previosly written code badly and I declared it outside function by mistake

Comment: But still the problem with same value of variable.. I've edited the original quesiton

Answer (score 1):

Instantiate the `chartData` in the callback instead of outside.

```
function loadGraph(chartDataStreams) {
    initCharts();
    for (c in chartDataStreams) {
        getDataFromServer(chartDataStreams[c].x, chartDataStreams[c].y, function (data) {

            var chartData = []; // RIGHT HERE

            for (d in data.datapoints) {
                var item = {
                    date: new Date(data.datapoints[d].at),
                    value: data.datapoints[d].value
                };
                chartData.push(item);
            }
            updateGraphData(chartData);
        });
    }
 }
```

This way each callback gets its own fresh `chartData` array when invoked.

Blocks do not create variable scope in JavaScript, only functions, so the outer `chartData` was scoped to the outer function, and was overwritten with each loop iteration.

Its last overwrite was what all the callbacks used when they were finally called, so all the data ended up in that shared array.

Comment: This is correct, but why?

Comment: Could you please check the original question? I edited it