# Callbacks created in $.each fn and with a for loop behave differently?

Tags: jquery, for-loop, each

all 
I made some of testing code that looks like this.

```
var selects = [$('#elem1'), $('#elem2'), $('#elem3')];

$.each(selects, function(item){
    selects[item].bind('click', function(){
        console.log("each function : " + item);
    });
});

for(var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++){
    var elem = selects[i];
    elem.bind('click', function(e){
        console.log("for loop : " + i);
    });
}
```

I made three buttons to be bound to event. and tested

If I click the button identified by name 'elem1', the result is :

```
console $
each function : 0
for loop : 3
```

and also If I click the button identified by name 'elem2', the result is :

```
console $
each function : 1
for loop : 3
```

What happened between two loop example? Please let me know.

Thank you, have a nice day.

Comment: you can search `javascript closure` in google for how and why.

Comment: Search SO for [`javascript loop last value`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+loop+last+value). There are [too] many duplicates. Once you find a suitable duplicate, please mark this question appropriately.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425062/passing-functions-to-settimeout-in-a-loop-always-the-last-value , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520587/variable-in-javascript-callback-functions-always-gets-last-value-in-loop , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example , etc

Comment: Thanks, I didn't hear what closure is. I'll check. and I am happy to understand this! Thanks pktangyue, pst, and Blender

Answer (score 0):

`i` refers to the counter variable itself, not the value of it. You have to pass it by value:

```
for(var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++){
    var elem = selects[i];

    (function(i) {
        elem.bind('click', function(e) {
            console.log("for loop : " + i);
        });
    })(i);
}
```

Shadowing `i` in an anonymous function does that.

Comment: Add that `$.fn.each` creates a new Execution Context for each iteration for a complete answer.