# call addEventListener in loop with variable

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

I am new to JavaScript. I have a 6 elements that I want to equip with very similar event listeners. I have a working brute force solution that I want to improve, but (I think) I have trouble with JavaScript closures.

Working code:

```
  elem = document.getElementById("court1button");
  elem.addEventListener("click", wassern_id1, false);
  elem = document.getElementById("court1xbutton");
  elem.addEventListener("click", abbrechen_id1, false);

  elem = document.getElementById("court2button");
  elem.addEventListener("click", wassern_id2, false);
  elem = document.getElementById("court2xbutton");
  elem.addEventListener("click", abbrechen_id2, false);

  ... 4 more times ...

  function wassern_id1(event) {
    wassern(1, event)
  }
  function wassern_id2(event) {
    wassern(2, event)
  }

  ... 4 more times ...

  function abbrechen_id1(event) {
    abbrechen(1, event)
  }
  function abbrechen_id2(event) {
    abbrechen(2, event)
  }

  ... 4 more times ...

  function wassern(id, event) { ...
  function abbrechen(id, event) { ...
```

I a simple loop that did not work, when I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/2520602/2536029 and understand why it could not work. Then I came up with the following code, that does not work either, but now I now longer understand why it does not work. Can someone explain it to me and help me create working code?

```
for (var id = 1; id <= 6; id++) {
  elem = document.getElementById("court" + id + "button");
  elem.addEventListener(
    "click",
    function(id2, event2){ 
      wassern(id2, event2); 
    }(id, event),
    false
  );
  elem = document.getElementById("court" + id + "xbutton");
  elem.addEventListener(
    "click",
    function(id2, event2){ 
      abbrechen(id2, event2); 
    }(id, event),
    false
  );
}
```

PS: the problem is, that `event` is undefined during the invocation of

```
function wassern(id, event) { ... event.stopPropagation();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to put event listener mechanism inside closure, in laymen closure return value from inner function, you want your event listener should be present even after loop is executed or scope is finished.

You need to wrap whole event or `getElementByid` inside closure, here is code snippet

```
  for (var id = 1; id <= 2; id++) {
     (function(id){
       elem = document.getElementById("court" + id + "button");
       elem.addEventListener(
        "click",
        function(event){wassern(id, event);},
        false
      );
      elem = document.getElementById("court" + id + "xbutton");
      elem.addEventListener(
        "click",
        function(event){abbrechen(id, event);},
        false
      );
    })(id)
  }
```

for getting event you can pass this, this refer to event inside `addEventListner`

Here is jsFiddle code http://jsfiddle.net/Xtgr4/

Hope above answer make sense to you

Comment: that passes on the actual MouseEvent. if you edit your answer to include that, i can accept it.